# What does it means { 0: T } in this type declaration?

Tags: typescript

I found in my code base this type declaration, as the name says is regarding non empty array:

```
type NonEmptyArray<T> = T[] & { 0: T }
```

and it works as expected:

```
const okay: NonEmptyArray<number> = [1, 2];
const alsoOkay: NonEmptyArray<number> = [1];
const err: NonEmptyArray<number> = []; // error!
```

Questions:

- 1  I am not able to understand what the `0` stand for in this part `{ 0: T }`. Could you please explain?
- 2  What is the different with alternative declaration?

`type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `{ 0: T }` `0` is just a key which matches index of first element of an array. Since in javascript arrays are subtype of object, it works just fine. I believe the alternative declaration provides the same result, but is a lot more simpler and easier to understand.
Maybe it was just code that worked with older version of typescript, spreading type in tuples is relatively new.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the generic type `T` and an intersection type (denoted by the `&` - the resulting type has all the fields of `T[]` and the type literal `{ 0: T}`), basically saying that this is an array of `T` that must have a zero index value of type `T`. In JavaScript, an array is a subtype of an object with all its indices being numbers; thus, any array can have its indices accessed in an object-like manner.